# Como resolver o problema do None no PYTHON

Tags: python

Por exemplo eu tenho este programa:

```
def bissexto (inicio,fim):
    """Diz quais são os anos bissextos"""
    for i in range (inicio,fim+1):
        if(i %4==0 and i %100!=0) or i %400==0:
            print(i,"- Bissexto")
        else:
            print(i,"- Não é bissexto")
inicio=int(input("Digite o primeiro ano"))
fim=int(input("Digite até quando quer saber"))
print(bissexto(inicio,fim))
```

Onde a saida é:

```
2000 - Bissexto
2001 - Não é bissexto
2002 - Não é bissexto
2003 - Não é bissexto
2004 - Bissexto
2005 - Não é bissexto
2006 - Não é bissexto
2007 - Não é bissexto
2008 - Bissexto
2009 - Não é bissexto
2010 - Não é bissexto
None
```

Como posso resolver este problema de aparecer o none no meu programa?

Comment: 1) [Não poste código como imagem](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5485/132); 2) A sua função `bissexto` não possui retorno, logo será `None`, ao fazer `print(bissexto(inicio, fim))` você está mandando exibir o retorno da função, `None`.

Comment: 1) Desculpe ter colocado imagens para mostrar a linhas de código, já resolvi esse problema 2)Obrigado, consegui resolver o problema

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O "None" só aparece por que voceê, na última linha, chama a função `bissexto`, e imprime o valor de retorno da mesma.

Como ela não tem um comando `return` explícito, ela retorna `None`, e o seu `print` imprime esse None.

Já que a sua função imprime ela mesma tudo o que você quer ver no programa, e não gera um valor de retorno que você vá usar, é só trocar a sua última linha por:

```
bissexto(inicio,fim)
```